# ng-repeat radio button 2-way binding issue, only last item set correctly

Tags: angularjs, input, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-value

I am using angularjs to repeat radio button groups with the following code.

```
<div class="row observation-point"
         ng-repeat="observationPoint in question.observationPointList">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <small>{{observationPoint.text}}</small>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" ng-disabled="observation.status != 'Open'"
                       name="{{domain.id}}-{{question.id}}-{{observationPoint.id}}"
                       id="{{domain.id}}-{{question.id}}-{{observationPoint.id}}-1" ng-value="true"
                       ng-model="observationPoint.observed">{{'observation-domain.html.yes' | translate}} {{observationPoint.observed}}
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" ng-disabled="observation.status != 'Open'"
                       name="{{domain.id}}-{{question.id}}-{{observationPoint.id}}"
                       id="{{domain.id}}-{{question.id}}-{{observationPoint.id}}-0" ng-value="false"
                       ng-model="observationPoint.observer">{{'observation-domain.html.no' | translate}}
            </label>


        </div>
    </div>
```

With angular 1.2.28 this worked fine, however we've recently upgraded to 1.4.2 and now the result is as in the picture below.

[image]

The model values are correctly saved and restored (see the true and false values in the image) in the variables, but only the last radio button in the ng-repeat is selected after reloading the page.

Why is this happening, because I really don't understand what the problem is and how to fix this.

nb. observationPoint.observer contains a boolean value not a string

EDIT: i've created a simplified plunker and of course this works as intended :S
http://plnkr.co/edit/tWjizHB8I5FNZVOgdq6J?p=preview

Which would suggest something is wrong with the naming or id's.
However when I check with the developer tools id and name seem fine
[image]

Comment: Looks like you have the same name for all of them, which makes them to be a signle group. And in a radio button group only one element can be selected at a time. You have to change the creation of the name for inputs to be dependant on your item from ng-repeat to have it a bit more dynamic

Comment: can you arrange the fiddle or plunker ?

Comment: @DianaR no, the names are unique for each group domain.id, question.id and observationpoint.id are all unique values. They are all dynamically named

Comment: Oh, yeah, I see it now. Hm need a plunkr or jsfidller to see what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the name and id are parsing correctly?

Comment: @DianaR i've created the plunker which works brilliantly, of course :S So this would suggest some naming issue. If only one random radio button group in the ng-repeat has a value it works fine, however when more have a value, only the last one is shown correctly. I've added a screenshot from the chrome developer tools. Maybe you can spot the issue. The page has several of these code blocks and they all indepently show the same issue which would suggest there is something wrong within the provided block

Comment: @ajmajmajma Well I was sure, i've added a screenshot of my chrome  developer tools to my original question. However the working plunker suggests there is a naming issue, but I can't see it

Comment: @TomDoes, can you please share one json that can be used to mimic exactly the name creation? I mean a json for `domain` and one for `question`

Comment: @DianaR I've added a domain.json file to the plunker

Comment: @TomDoes yeah, but the `question` and `domain` object examples are not there. Please add them too.

Comment: @DianaR The domain has a list of questions which in turn has of a list of observationpoints. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Yeah, this is what I mean. If you could add one example of domain (together with it's question list) so that I could refference in html for dynamic name creation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89699/discussion-between-tomdoes-and-diana-r).

Comment: Yeah, sure. I just joined the room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution, if I change the dynamic names from

```
name="{{domain.id}}-{{question.id}}-{{observationPoint.id}}"
```

to

```
name="observationPoint_{{observationPoint.id}}"
```

it works without a hitch. I presume there is some sort of loading/timing issue going on. The variables are probably not unique at the moment the UI is rendered and causes only the last item to be set.